# Expected value for advent of code (average case complexity)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, computational-complexity

With the upcoming advent of code I was looking at past problems and noted that one was easily solved with an algorithm such that for a length $n$ array, the algorithm finishes as soon as you encounter the second of two numbers that are randomly distributed within it.

I was trying to figure out **the expected value for the number of items you need to look at out of $n$ randomly distributed items before finding two values of interest**, but my probability is rusty.

I think I could finish the problem if I could nail down the combinatorics, but my combinatorics is too rusty.

There are clearly $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ items. The number of ways for the two items of interest to be in the first two items you look at is clearly $2$, so the expected value is $2\cdot 2/n!+3\cdot a_3/n!+\cdots +n\cdot a_{n}/n!$

I *think* if I could figure out the number of ways to arrange the 2 different items in a line of length $k$, then $a_k$ should be that number minus all the ways for $k-1$.

Am I okay so far? Can you help me finish the combinatorics solution?

I'm open to other smarter ways to solve the problem too but I'd like in particular to figure out the combinatorics.

What's the expected value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Okay, I bolded the central question

Comment: evidently  https://adventofcode.com/2021/events

Comment: The specific problem is https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1 but the question isn't very much related to that (indeed it would depend on the algorithm you used..) and the problem is trivial anyway - what I'm really trying to get a handle on is the probability necessary for tackling *average case* algorithmic complexity here

Comment: (In particular there's an obvious caching solution that terminates after checking $k$ of the $n$ numbers as soon as you've encountered both items of interest) i.e. place in a hash set 2020-x for each number x you encounter then check containment in the set (O(1)) for each next item you encounter
This is assuming there are only 2 numbers that sum to 2020 in the set which I'm fine with assuming

Comment: It turns out the expected number of turns is $\frac23(n-2)+2$, but I do not know how to explain it with combinatorics directly the way you want, only with probability (specifically, linearity of expectation).

Comment: @Mike Post the answer explaining the approach anyway :) I prefer understanding as many ways to solve a problem as I can

Comment: I'm willing to accept I'm shoving a square peg in a round hole by approaching this with combinatorics even if I'd still like to solve it that way once (along with learning the round peg solution(s)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $P(k)$ to be the probability that it takes $k$ searches to find both items of interest. There are $n!$ ways to arrange the $n$ objects. You will find $A$ and $B$ in exactly $k$ searches if one of $A$ or $B$ is the $k^\text{th}$ object you search and the other is searched before. There are $2$ ways to choose which special item is the $k^\text{th}$ object searched, and there are $k-1$ ways to choose where to put the other special item. There are $(n-2)!$ ways to arrange the other items.

Hence, $P(k)=\frac{2(n-2)!(k-1)}{n!}=\frac{2(k-1)}{n(n-1)}$. The expected value is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n P(k)k$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k(k-1)}{n(n-1)}$$
$$=\frac{4}{n(n-1)}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$
$$=\frac{4}{n(n-1)}\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{k}{2}$$
$$=\frac{4}{n(n-1)}\binom{n+1}{3}$$
$$=\frac{2(n+1)}{3}$$

Comment: @OP In your work, $a_k=P(k)n!$

Comment: Ahah! Nice. Good way to find $P(k)$; I struggled over Thanksgiving family stuff and couldn't quite nail it.

Comment: I looked at this again and I think we're both making this harder than it is by treating A and B as different.

Comment: How about $P(k)=(k-1)/{n\choose 2}$

Comment: Leave your answer though! I might post another or see if someone else wants to elaborate this method

Comment: My binomial form for P(k) is evidently correct, but I'm unhappy with it; I always end up confusing myself when I try to use combinations in this manner instead of the full n!. Is it just me? Can I overcome my combination disability?

Comment: @Freakadilly I don't think too much difficulty comes from the way I did it. I am still using a lot of symmetry for $A$ and $B$ (hence the multiplication by $2$). I also think in the more general problem, my approach doesn't get too tedious anyway. I think there might be some interesting interpretation that results in your expression for $P(k)$, but I can't think of one.

Comment: Ah I figured out the interpretation that leads to it. I'll post an answer with it and accept yours I think.

Comment: What do you think?: The number of ways to highlight which two items in a list are the ones of interest is n choose 2, and the amount of those where one item is on $k$ is $k-1$ (number of places to put second item). This fully builds in the symmetry

Comment: Okay I posted the general solution

Answer (score 4):

**Answer:** The expected number of objects looked at is $\frac23(n-2)+2$.

Call the special objects you need to collect $A$ and $B$, and let $X$ be an arbitrary other object. What is the probability that you will look at $X$ before looking at both $A$ and $B$? The answer is $2/3$. This can be seen by listing all $3!=6$ orderings for the objects $A$, $B$, and $X$, and counting that there are $4$ orderings where $X$ is not last.

Since there are $n-2$ other objects besides $A$ and $B$, and each has a probability of $2/3$ of being looked at, linearity of expectation implies that the expected number of other objects seen is $\frac23(n-2)$. To get the total number of objects looked at, we add two to that, for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Great solution thanks. I'll keep linearity of expectation in my toolkit now; I'll upvote when I get enough rep to (need 15 apparently).

Comment: Woah very nice. Linearity of expectation solutions never cease to amaze me!

Comment: I think I posted the generalization of this as a separate answer, to double check my understanding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $a$ objects of interest among $n$ objects instead of $2$ of interest like in the question. We solve it via linearity of expectation and a different combinatorics approach.

The chance a given object of noninterest occurs after $a$ objects of interest is $1/(a+1)$ so the expectation to encounter any individual object is $a/(a+1)$. By linearity of expectation the expectation for how many of the $n-a$ objects you see is $a(n-a)/(a+1)$. The total number of objects you look at is then $a(n-a)/(a+1)+a$ which simplifies to $a(n+1)/(a+1)$ and answers my question when $a=2$.

Let the binomial coefficient/combination be $C(a,b)$. There are $C(n,a)$ ways to choose which $a$ items are the items of interest. If the last item of interest is at position $k$, there are $a-1$ remaining items of interest to be fit into the previous $k-1$ items, so $C(k-1,a-1)$ is the number of ways to choose them. Therefore the probability $P(k)$ you've found all $a$ items of interest in exactly $k$ items is $C(k-1,a-1)/C(n,a)$. The expectation is therefore $\sum_{k=a}^{n}kC(k-1,a-1)/C(n,a)$ which simplifies to $a(n+1)/(a+1)$.

Comment: If I analytically continue the discrete probability distribution the median when $a=2$ is (sqrt(2 n^2 - 2 n + 1) + 1)/2 apparently